# How to remove title area from ionicPopup

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I want to remove the title area from the ionic popup completely. I removed the title tag and tried. but still can see the title space visible. Here is my code.

```
 var registerPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

        templateUrl: 'templates/register_popup.html',

        scope: $scope

    });
```

Even if I remove the title tag completely, the title area is still visible with a blank space as shown in the image below. I want to remove the entire title space from the  ionicPopup. How can I get it? what changes are to be made in the code?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is because the title is wrapped inside `.popup-head` which takes the space.

First add a value of `custom-class` to `cssClass` property in the Popup object.

```
var registerPopup = $ionicPopup.show({

    templateUrl: 'templates/register_popup.html',
    cssClass: 'custom-class', // Add
    scope: $scope

});
```

You can hide it using custom CSS.

```
.custom-class .popup-head {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) Also how did you find out ? it is not mention in the doc

Comment: This is too broad to be mentioned in the docs :) We can get help from the other things mentioned in the docs and implement it.